# Set dynamic value to Array in JS like PHP

Tags: javascript, php

My question is how I will set a value an array in JS like PHP?
for example:
in php I have an array named Arr, I set a new value in n position using

```
Arr[] = value
```

*but I try to do same in JS but display an error*

Comment: By the way, google is your friend, searching 'javascript array': http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Comment: @Jorge you have answers, try them. which one looks more elaborated and useful mark as an answer . thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the push command

```
Arr.push(value)
```